# How to not propagate private IP address?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone

I have 2 MS 2016 DNS servers that are only used as Public Name Servers.  I cannot seem to figure out how to not propagate their private IP address. I've been told to use Microsoft DNS Policy Filtering, however I'm at a loss.

I delete the A records containing the private IP, however after a few minutes they are back in the record.  As a work around, I have a script deleting them every 2 minutes.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Lon

Answer (score 2):

DNS records don't propagate. The DNS server is going to register an A record for the ip address that is bound to the DNS server, which is the ip address assigned to the NIC. If you don't want it to register an A record for the private ip address then assign the NIC a public ip address and bind the DNS server to that ip address.